# Hint for solving $\int \frac{(1+b)x + a\sqrt{1- x^2}}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int \dfrac{(1+b)x + a\sqrt{1- x^2}}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b}dx$$

where a and b are the arbitrary real number.

**My first attempt:** 
$$\int \dfrac{(1+b)x + a\sqrt{1- x^2}}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b}dx = \int\frac{1}{x}dx + \int\dfrac{b}{x[(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b]}dx$$

**My second attempt:**
$$\int \dfrac{(1+b)x + a\sqrt{1- x^2}}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b}dx = \int\dfrac{((1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b)'}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b} + \int\dfrac{\frac{ax^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-(1+b)x}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2}-b}dx$$
 But they did not work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to proceed, is to set

$$x = \sin\theta ~~~~~ \text{d}x = \cos\theta \ \text{d}\theta$$

And you get:

$$\int \frac{A\sin\theta\cos\theta + a\cos^2\theta}{A\sin^2\theta + a\sin\theta\cos\theta - b}\ \text{d}\theta$$

For the sake of simplicity I called $A = 1+b$

Now if you take a look at the denominator you can see that the numerator can be its derivative if you add and cut some terms.

Precisely, if you transform the numerator in this way:

$$A\sin\theta\cos\theta + a\cos^2\theta \to $$ $$ A\sin\theta\cos\theta + a\cos^2\theta + A\sin\theta\cos\theta - A\sin\theta\cos\theta + a\sin^2\theta - a\sin^2\theta$$

You obtain that the part

$$2A\sin\theta\cos\theta + a\cos^2\theta - a\sin^2\theta$$ is the derivative of the denominator, hence you obtain a form

$$\frac{f'}{f}$$

which you can immediately solve as

$$\log\left(A\sin^2\theta + a\sin\theta\cos\theta - b\right)$$

What remains is this:

$$\int\frac{a\sin^2\theta - A\sin\theta\cos\theta}{A\sin^2\theta + a\sin\theta\cos\theta - b} \ \text{d}\theta$$

**I'm going to think about this**

Answer (score 0):

You can use (according to Mathematica):

$$\frac{(1+b)x + a\sqrt{1- x^2}}{(1+b)x^2 + ax\sqrt{1-x^2} -b}=-\frac{a\,b\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^4(a^2+(1+b)^2)-x^2(a^2+2b\,(1+b))+b^2}+\frac{x^3(a^2+(1+b)^2)-x(a^2+b(1+b))}{x^4(a^2+(1+b)^2)-x^2(a^2+2b\,(1+b))+b^2}$$

The first integral is quite cumbersome but solveable, the second one is a combination of arctanh and ln.